How to make an absolute div inside a fixed div to be behind it?
I totaly need to have container to be fixed on the page (wherever I scroll) to make the inner one appearing from behind the fixed one (by click on smth, it doesn't matter).
I mean like:
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">    
  </div>
</div>

<style>
.container {
  position: fixed;
  left: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
</style>

Many thanks :)

Wouldn't ::backdrop be more appropriate?
